# Links In HTML iFrame Won't Open In Parent Window

Tags: html, iframe, hyperlink

I have an iframe in HTML, but the links from the iframe open within the iframe. I tried adding **target="_parent"**, but the hyperlicks still open within the iFrame.

`<iframe src="misc.php?page=UnitedStatesMap" target="_parent" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

I am really new to StackOverFlow, and HTML in general. So this is probably a really dumb question. Sorry, but I just can't figure this out.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The target needs to go in the head of the HTML page within the iframe. IE the iframe page should have:

```
<head>
 <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

[See here for more](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp).

If you want a link on your page to open in the iFrame you would do [something like](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp):

```
 <iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" name="iframe_a"></iframe>
 <p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

As far as I know I don't think it's possible to control where links open just through the iFrame attributes.